# Wordpress theme header wont show up after database modification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been working on a Wordpress theme integrated with Woo-commerce.

While I was editing the theme the header section states "Free Shipping On All Orders Above $75". I wanted it to be $100 and I managed to find that the information is inside the `wp_options` table in the database. After editing the text to $100 my header and footer sections won't show up.

I would like to know where the issue is and why both of my sections won't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wp_options` table contains theme (and plugin) settings stored as user options in the database. That user data many times is saved as serialized data; that format saves space.

When you directly edit and resave a theme's data in `wp_options` with phpmyadmin or adminer, you are breaking the serialized data string, and as a result, break the theme's settings.

The database tools phpmyadmin or adminer are not designed for and have no way to unserialize and then reserialize that you are editing.

So don't edit theme options directly in `wp_options` unless it is absolutely necessary. Make theme changes in the theme's PHP code, in localization strings, in HTML, whatever.

To get the header and footer back, resave all your theme settings to reset the theme; or worst case, deactivate the theme and hope that the theme clears out its own database tables and settings so you can start over with your customizations.